# Input field state changes on React

Tags: reactjs, state, input-field

Trying to figure out why the following:

```
handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.id, event.target.value)
    this.setState({
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log("New state: ", this.state.buyin)
};
```

Logs "undefined"? The first log is "buyin", (whatever I type in the box) Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

Greetings,

Bram

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous, so `this.state.buyin` will not be set until the state has been updated.

You can use the second argument to `setState` which is a callback function that is run when the state has been updated.

```
handleChange = event => {
  console.log(event.target.id, event.target.value);
  this.setState(
    {
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    },
    () => console.log("New state: ", this.state)
  );
};
```

Comment: That gave some enlightment, cheers for that. But I still get the undefined error?

Comment: @BramWesselink I see. I might have misunderstood your question. Do you think you could elaborate a bit more about what you mean? Could you include your entire component in the question? Do you mean that what you have written in the input is `buyin`? That is the value that the `id` key will have. The state will not have a `buyin` key if that's the case. You can log just `this.state` to see what I mean.

Comment: Well, I just found out I retarded. The "this.state.buyin" is nothing, its this.state.buyin_price. But you still helped me alot with your awnser! It tackled the root of the problem, cheers for that.